# FIR filter coefficients from frequency responses

Tags: matlab, filters, filter-design, lowpass-filter, finite-impulse-response

I have frequency responses of FIR filter of order 13 from obtained 50 frequency samples. How can I get FIR filter coefficients of order 13?

For example, in MATLAB a lot of possible ways I tried ;

I have a frequency samples : `w=[0 1]` (1x50)

I have frequency responses of FIR filter of order 13: `hd` (1x50)

```
b1=fir1(12,wc) % b1:FIR filter ideal coefficients of order 13

hd=freqz(b1,1,w) %hd :FIR filter frequency responses with respect to b1
```

1. When I apply inverse fourier transform to FIR filter frequency responses ( `ifft(hd,13)` ), I don't reach b1. I am supposed to reach b1 coefficients in theory. Am I right?
2. I apply inverse fft shift for moving to true domain before apply Fourier Transform( `ifft( ifftshift(hdg),13)` ) but also I don't reach b1. So what else can I do?

There is incompatible things(may be between frequencies and transforms ) I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

The frequency argument for `freqz()` should be in radians/second, not normalized frequency in `[0,1)`. It has a form that makes it easy for you:

```
% length of frequency response vector
N = 50;
% cutoff frequency
wc = 0.25;
% design 12th-order lowpass filter
b1 = fir1(12, wc);
% calculate its frequency response at `N` points around unit circle
hd = freqz(b1, 1, N, 'whole');
% inverse transform the frequency response
b2 = ifft(hd);
% `b1` and `b2` should be the same.
plot(1:length(b1), b1, 1:length(b2), b2);
```

This yields the plot:

[image]

You only see one trace because they are right on top of one another, as they should be. `b2` is longer in duration because it has the same length as the frequency response vector, which was arbitrarily chosen to have length 50.

Comment: So do you have any idea how to convert normalized frequencies (w) to radians/second ?

Comment: Multiply by $\pi$. You'll need to cover the full range from $0$ to $2\pi$ in order to get the result shown above. `fir1` only deals in real filters, so its cutoff frequency is always between $0$ and $\pi$ radians/second.